# Rewrite Url to a SEO-friendly format

Tags: url-rewriting, seo

I am using a membership plugin and I would like to change the user-profile Urls.

Example Url:

http://rec-orders.de/?p_action=user_profile&post_author=2044

This is how the new Url shall look like:

http://rec-orders.de/fotograf/username-2044

Any ideas? 
Thanks and kind regards,

Chris

Comment: What permalink option have you chosen under `Settings -> Permalinks` ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with the built-in `$wp_rewrite` global.  Something like this should give you a good start:

```
function new_rewrite_rules(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $keytag = '%user_id%';
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag($keytag, '(.+?)', 'user=');
    $structure = $wp_rewrite->root . "username-$keytag/";
    $rewrite = $wp_rewrite->generate_rewrite_rules($structure);                
    if(!is_array($wp_rewrite->rules)) $wp_rewrite->rules = array();
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $rewrite + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    return $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

You would then access your variable inside the loop via `$wp_query->query_vars['user']`.

Note that this only makes your URL schema valid, in order to make the new url display you'll have to change the way links are  generated in the membership plugin so that they match your schema.  Ideally, the plugin will have a filter that lets you change it.

Comment: Great! I will make a few tests with your code - thank you so far!